# Radiobutton.Checked not working for first button in group

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

I've got a check for the first radiobutton in my group of ASP.NET radiobuttons.  For some reason, the page loads and that first button is automatically checked, not that we're setting it to be checked..it must naturally check itself since it's the first in the group.

However, when I actually check that it's checked in an if statement (so that I can act on it) it returns false even though it's checked for sure when the page renders

`myRadioButton.Checked` ends up with false.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

ended up being a logic problem.  I was binding after my check logic.

Answer (score 0):

My dollars are that you're setting the button state during `Page_Load` and forgetting to check whether `IsPostBack` is true/false.  Your code likely looks like this:

```
Page_Load(...) {
  SetFormState()
}
```

When it should look like this:

```
Page_Load(...) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
      SetFormState()
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, we are not setting the default selected radio button anywhere in our code